# MySQL group-by very slow

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I have the folowwing SQL query

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM sales WHERE `Date` <= '2012-01-01' GROUP BY CustomerID
```

The query is executed over 11400000 rows and runs very slow. It takes over 3 minutes to execute. If I remove the group-by part, this runs below 1 second. Why is that?

MySQL Server version is '5.0.21-community-nt'

```
Here is the table schema:
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `DocNo` int(11) default '0',
  `CustomerID` int(11) default '0',
  `OperatorID` int(11) default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  KEY `DocNo` (`DocNo`),
  KEY `CustomerID` (`CustomerID`),
  KEY `Date` (`Date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=14946509 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: can you post table schema (create script of table)

Comment: Not sure if you posted the actual query or not. But in this query what would be the need to `GROUP BY` if there are no grouping functions?

Comment: Aziz, I need to return the unique values of customerID

Comment: In this case, use `DISTINCT` in your query and remove `GROUP BY`. Something like `SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID ...`

Answer (score 30):

Try putting an index on (Date,CustomerID).

Have a look at the mysql manual for optimizing group by queries:- [Group by optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html)

You can find out how mysql is generating the result if you use `EXPLAIN` as follows:-

```
EXPLAIN SELECT CustomerID FROM sales WHERE `Date` <= '2012-01-01' GROUP BY CustomerID
```

This will tell you which indexes (if any) mysql is using to optimize the query. This is very handy when learning which indexes work for which queries as you can try creating an index and see if mysql uses it. So even if you don't fully understand how mysql calculates aggregate queries you can create a useful index by trial and error.

Comment: As someone who's just beginning to get the hang of optomizing queries and tables, this little nugget was invaluable. Thank you.

Comment: @ArthurGoldsmith No worries :)

Comment: @rgvcorley - I seriously owe you lunch. Why I didn't know about this indexing thing I don't know. But dayam that is fast now :)

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing what your table schema looks like, it's difficult to be certain, but it would probably help if you added a multiple-column index on `Date` and `CustomerID`. That'd save MySQL the hassle of doing a full table scan for the `GROUP BY` statement. So try `ALTER TABLE sales ADD INDEX (Date,CustomerID)`.

Answer (score 2):

try this one :

```
SELECT distinct CustomerID FROM sales WHERE `Date` <= '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: in mysql distinct is just a special case of a group by http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT is much faster for me than SELECT...GROUP BY. On a 15 million row table with appropriate indexes and sorting the results ASC, SELECT...GROUP BY takes about 3.5 seconds, while SELECT DISTINCT takes about 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I changed the key fields to the same Collation and that fix the problem. Fields to join the tables had different Collate value.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this one be a lot faster and achieve the same?

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM sales WHERE `Date` <= '2012-01-01'
```

Make sure to place an index on `Date`, of course. I'm not entirely sure but indexing `CustomerID` might also help.