# mysql query group by takes long time

Tags: mysql, group-by

hi I have a items table with 400k records

My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `short_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
  `Sku` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `short_description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'enable',
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `indian_price` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price_old` double NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

When I execute the following query without `GROUP BY Sku`  Query took 0.2651 seconds.

```
select 
      item_id, 
      short_name, 
      price, 
      price_above,
      Sku 
   from 
      items 
   where 
      category_id in ('1', '20', '21', '43', '56', '61', '74', '94', '259',
  '22', '38', '42', '51', '52', '55', '57', '70', '117', '117', '121',
  '147', '151', '177', '181', '121', '117', '121', '147', '151', '177',
  '181', '147', '117', '121', '147', '151', '177', '181', '151', '117',
  '121', '147', '151', '177', '181', '177', '117', '121', '147', '151',
  '177', '181', '181', '117', '121', '147', '151', '177', '181', '79', 
  '80', '84', '85', '24', '46', '63', '68', '72', '26', '39', '40', 
  '78', '100', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', 
  '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150',
  '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '111',
  '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', 
  '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', 
  '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '112', '100', '111', 
  '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', 
  '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', 
  '174', '175', '176', '180', '113', '100', '111', '112', '113', 
  '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', 
  '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', 
  '176', '180', '114', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', 
  '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146',
  '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180',
  '115', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120',
  '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160',
  '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '116', '100',
  '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141',
  '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172',
  '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '120', '100', '111', '112',
  '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143',
  '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174',
  '175', '176', '180', '130', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114',
  '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145',
  '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176',
  '180', '141', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116',
  '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150',
  '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '142',
  '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130',
  '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171',
  '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '143', '100', '111',
  '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142',
  '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173',
  '174', '175', '176', '180', '144', '100', '111', '112', '113',
  '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144',
  '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175',
  '176', '180', '145', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115',
  '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146',
  '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180',
  '146', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120',
  '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160',
  '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '150', '100',
  '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141',
  '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172',
  '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '160', '100', '111', '112',
  '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143',
  '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174',
  '175', '176', '180', '171', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114',
  '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145',
  '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176',
  '180', '172', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116',
  '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150',
  '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '173',
  '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130',
  '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171',
  '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '174', '100', '111',
  '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142',
  '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173',
  '174', '175', '176', '180', '175', '100', '111', '112', '113',
  '114', '115', '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144',
  '145', '146', '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175',
  '176', '180', '176', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115',
  '116', '120', '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146',
  '150', '160', '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180',
  '180', '100', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '120',
  '130', '141', '142', '143', '144', '145', '146', '150', '160',
  '171', '172', '173', '174', '175', '176', '180', '92', '98',
  '28', '29', '36', '44', '53', '59', '81', '82', '83', '90',
  '95', '118', '118', '124', '125', '126', '148', '154', '155',
  '156', '178', '184', '185', '186', '124', '118', '124', '125',
  '126', '148', '154', '155', '156', '178', '184', '185', '186',
  '125', '118', '124', '125', '126', '148', '154', '155', '156',
  '178', '184', '185', '186', '126', '118', '124', '125', '126',
  '148', '154', '155', '156', '178', '184', '185', '186', '148',
  '118', '124', '125', '126', '148', '154', '155', '156', '178',
  '184', '185', '186', '154', '118', '124', '125', '126', '148',
  '154', '155', '156', '178', '184', '185', '186', '155', '118',
  '124', '125', '126', '148', '154', '155', '156', '178', '184',
  '185', '186', '156', '118', '124', '125', '126', '148', '154',
  '155', '156', '178', '184', '185', '186', '178', '118', '124',
  '125', '126', '148', '154', '155', '156', '178', '184', '185',
  '186', '184', '118', '124', '125', '126', '148', '154', '155',
  '156', '178', '184', '185', '186', '185', '118', '124', '125',
  '126', '148', '154', '155', '156', '178', '184', '185', '186',
  '186', '118', '124', '125', '126', '148', '154', '155', '156',
  '178', '184', '185', '186', '96', '246', '30', '31', '37', '101',
  '101', '128', '131', '158', '161', '188', '128', '101', '128', 
  '131', '158', '161', '188', '131', '101', '128', '131', '158', 
  '161', '188', '158', '101', '128', '131', '158', '161', '188', 
  '161', '101', '128', '131', '158', '161', '188', '188', '101', 
  '128', '131', '158', '161', '188', '41', '54', '58', '69', '86', 
  '87', '89', '91', '129', '129', '159', '159', '129', '159', '32', 
  '242', '243', '244', '279', '280', '281', '247', '248', '249', 
  '250', '251', '252', '253', '254', '255', '256', '277', '278', 
  '257', '258') 

      and category_id not in ('243', '254', '40', '251', '80', 
     '250', '256', '248', '98', '39', '249', '52')  
   order by 
      Price asc 
   limit 20 
      offset 480;
```

And when i execute following query with `GROUP BY Sku` Query took 4.9728 seconds.

```
select
      ( same query content as above )
   group by
      Sku 
   order by
      Price asc 
   limit 
      20 offset 480
```

Indexes of my table[Indexes of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g00I.png)

Why does this happen? please help me to resolve this? how can I speed up a query with GROUP BY Sku?

Comment: If you ask about performance and don't add the info about your indexes we can't help you

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278878/mysql-group-by-very-slow/10278957

Comment: @juergend I have attached the image of index details please check it out

Comment: @AmanjotKaur I checked it already its does help for me

Comment: execute sql query with EXPLAIN statement to properly analyse query to determine whether indexes are used by query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too big for a comment.

1. Why you have so many indexes on your table(Not sure if it is for all other queries)? Having too much indexes on the table also deceases the performance.
2. When there is no aggregate function, Why are you using a group by clause in your query?
3. For your given query, Having index only on column `category_id` is sufficient. You might try a composite index with price column also with `category_id` column.

Last, Please share the EXPLAIN PLAN also to get better help.

Comment: You might consider accepting answer and upvote in that case. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning up the visual post of the query, I see you have a list of 923 actual entries within your Category_ID IN clause... Of those, wrote a quick routine to break down the numbers and found you have 25 instances of many numbers (such as 100-116, 120, 130, 141-146, 150, 160, 171-176, 180).  Others you have 13 instances of 12 other numbers, 7 instances of even others.  So where your list of originating values is coming from, I would get distinct from that.  Also, since the data type of the category_id is integer, your IN list should be integers and without quotes.

You ALSO have an "and category_id NOT IN" clause... how are these numbers getting seletcted, why populate two lists unless one is an explicit exclusion.  You may want to add a column to the items table wish some sort of flag column to simplify as

AND ExcludeFlag = 0    (ex: set to 1 if you want to exclude from query)

As for an index to optimize, your WHERE clause is the primary basis and should be in first position.  Then, if you NEED the Sku for group by (such as the max price per Sku), add Sku as second position.  Finally, you order by price. put this in third position.  It will also help such as a max( price ) grouped by SKU

index on... ( category_id, sku, price )

if NO group by, just ( category_id, price )

As Ankit mentioned, you have a group by, but no aggregate (sum, min, max, count, etc.) so why have the group by.  If it is NOT needed, get rid of it.