# mysql many tables, multiple columns group by

Tags: mysql, performance

The table I have configured is as follows.

```
TABLE CAT{
  ID number primary key,
  CATNAME varchar2,
  ...
}

<Many-to-Many>
TABLE CAT_CHARR{
  CATID number,
  CHARRID number
}

TABLE CHARR{
  ID number,
  CHARRNAME varchar2,
  SPECIES varchar2,
 ...
}
```

cats have its own characteristics, and those characteristics were considered characteristics unique to that species.

```
INSERT INTO CHARR(CHARRNAME, SPECIES) VALUES ( 'BLUE FUR', 'russianblue');
INSERT INTO CHARR(CHARRNAME, SPECIES) VALUES ( 'NO FUR', 'sphinx');
...
```

Duplication is possible as follows.

```
INSERT INTO CAT_CHARR(CATID, CHARRID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO CAT_CHARR(CATID, CHARRID) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO CAT_CHARR(CATID, CHARRID) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO CAT_CHARR(CATID, CHARRID) VALUES (1, 3);
```

I want to calculate only the highest trait of each cat's species.

```
SELECT CAT.ID, CHARR.SPECIES, CHARR.CHARRNAME, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM CAT
INNER CAT_CHARR ON CAT.ID = CAT_CHARR.CATID
INNER JOIN CHARR ON CHARR.ID = CAT_CHARR.CHARRID
GROUP BY CAT.ID, CHARR.SPECIES, CHARR.CHARRNAME
```

If there is no group by, the speed is fast.
But if there are group by and count(*), the speed is too slow.

I used google translate, so the explanation might be a little weird.
If you write a comment, I'll try harder to translate. Sorry

Comment: Please add full table definitions so that we can see the engine,collation and indexes, add an explain plan and give us an idea of numbers . also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278878/mysql-group-by-very-slow and check that your select  has no limit imposed by your ui

Comment: The duplicate `(1,1)` is getting in the way of optimization; what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Users insert a feature with duplicates, and I try to calculate the cat's species probability with the most inserted value.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN costly operation you can replace this. And you get something like this

```
SELECT CAT.ID, CHARR.SPECIES, CHARR.CHARRNAME, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM CAT, CAT_CHARR, CHARR
WHERE CAT.ID = CAT_CHARR.CATID AND CHARR.ID = CAT_CHARR.CHARRID AND CHARR.ID = CAT.ID
GROUP BY CAT.ID, CHARR.SPECIES, CHARR.CHARRNAME
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it is similar to or slower than inner join.

Comment: In theory, it should be a little faster

Comment: The optimizer treats them as the same.  It is better (for humans) to use the newer0 `JOIN...ON` instead of `FROM a,b WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

For performance the many-to-many table needs

```
PRIMARY KEY(catid, carrid),
INDEX(carrid, catid)
```

(or vice versa)